# Chrome Extension that acts upon URL

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, google-chrome-extension

I'm very new to developing extensions for google chrome. What I would like my extension to do is upon the user entering a url, compare that url (or part of it) to a list hosted somewhere and then perform an action that may edit the url if it meets some criteria. If it helps, for now we can consider that criteria to be simple membership in the list. I would like this to be done in javascript, but any solution is much appreciated.

I can flesh out the details more to the best of my knowledge if it would help generate an answer or ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is [`chrome.webNavigation`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html).
If you catch `from_address_bar` events, you can then navigate away.

Unfortunately, there is no ability to edit the contents of the location bar, as far as I can tell. I needed it for my extension as well.